# Help identify: astronomer grandfather is trapped on a distant planet as a mine slave?

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

Through a telescope, the grandson sees his grandfather trapped in a distant planet, working in mines as a slave under the whip of bug like creatures.

I saw it in the 70s when I was maybe 9 years old, and it was already an old movie. I do not remember if it was in black and white or color. Maybe it was a movie or an episode of something like *The Outer Limits*. But the description tells how it ended.

Comment: any other details you can think of that might help? new movie? old movie? tv episode? book?

Comment: i saw it in the 70s when i was maybe 9 years old, and it was already an old movie. I do not remember if it was in black and white or color. Maybe it was a movie or an episode of something like The Outer Limits. But the description tells how it ended.

Comment: Ah. The fact that it was a film is important. :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe: [First Men in the Moon (1964)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Men_in_the_Moon_(1964_film))

Its been a long time since I have seen it.
Reasons why maybe not, There is no grandson. The story teller (old man) is 
 recalling events that happened 40? years before.

Man has landed on the moon and find a note which leads back to Arnold Bedford. They find him and ask him how it got there.

I THINK he starts looking through a telescope at the moon as he recalls the events of the movie in a flashback. His story ends when he (and his fiancée) escape in the ship leaving the grandfatherly older gentleman (Cavor) who invented the ship behind (he aids their escape) on the moon being taking away by the bugs. At which point he stops looking through the telescope.

Comment: The First men in the Moon must happen in or after the year it was released.  As I remember the visit to the Moon happened in 1897 according to the note claiming the Moon, and thus at least 67 years earlier.  I don't remember him looking through the telescope while telling his story.   One the other hand, I don't remember any movie or TV show more like the question.